# How can I hyperlink calendar days that have post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a class that is used to display a calendar.

What I now want is the following: As the week days are shown, I want to hyperlink all the days that have post under category events.

I was thinking of adding the loop inside the function that prints the days like this:

```
function getWeekDays() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', // the post type
        'category_name' => 'events', // name of category
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'field_name', // the name of the custom date field
            'value' => '20190715', // the date to compare it with
            'compare' => '='
            )
        ),
    );
    $events_dates = new WP_Query( $args );

    $weekLength = $this->getWeekLengthByMonth ();
    $firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
    $weekDays = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $weekLength; $i ++) {
        for($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j ++) {
            $cellIndex = $i * 7 + $j;
            $cellValue = null;
            if ($cellIndex == $firstDayOfTheWeek) {
                $this->currentDay = 1;
            }
            if (! empty ( $this->currentDay ) && $this->currentDay <= $this->currentMonthDaysLength) {
                $cellValue = $this->currentDay;
                $this->currentDay ++;
            }
            $weekDays .= '<li>' . $cellValue . '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $weekDays;
}
```

The entire class looks like the following:

```
<?php
class calendarWidget{
    private $weekDayName = array ("MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN");
    private $currentDay = 0;
    private $currentMonth = 0;
    private $currentYear = 0;
    private $currentMonthStart = null;
    private $currentMonthDaysLength = null; 

    function __construct() {

        $this->currentYear = date ( "Y", time () );
        $this->currentMonth = date ( "m", time () );

        if (! empty ( $_POST ['year'] )) {
            $this->currentYear = $_POST ['year'];
        }
        if (! empty ( $_POST ['month'] )) {
            $this->currentMonth = $_POST ['month'];
        }
        $this->currentMonthStart = $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-01';
        $this->currentMonthDaysLength = date ( 't', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
    }

    function getCalendarHTML() {
        $calendarHTML = '<div id="calendar-outer">'; 
        $calendarHTML .= '<div class="calendar-nav">' . $this->getCalendarNavigation() . '</div>'; 
        $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-name-title">' . $this->getWeekDayName () . '</ul>';
        $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-day-cell">' . $this->getWeekDays () . '</ul>';        
        $calendarHTML .= '</div>';
        return $calendarHTML;
    }

    function getCalendarNavigation() {
        $prevMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart. ' -1 Month'  ) );
        $prevMonthYearArray = explode(",",$prevMonthYear);

        $nextMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart . ' +1 Month'  ) );
        $nextMonthYearArray = explode(",",$nextMonthYear);

        $navigationHTML = '<div class="prev" data-prev-month="' . $prevMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-prev-year = "' . $prevMonthYearArray[1]. '"><</div>'; 
        $navigationHTML .= '<span id="currentMonth">' . date ( 'M ', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
        $navigationHTML .= '<span contenteditable="true" id="currentYear">'.    date ( 'Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
        $navigationHTML .= '<div class="next" data-next-month="' . $nextMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-next-year = "' . $nextMonthYearArray[1]. '">></div>';
        return $navigationHTML;
    }

    function getWeekDayName() {
        $WeekDayName= '';       
        foreach ( $this->weekDayName as $dayname ) {            
            $WeekDayName.= '<li>' . $dayname . '</li>';
        }       
        return $WeekDayName;
    }

    function getWeekDays() {            
        $weekLength = $this->getWeekLengthByMonth ();
        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
        $weekDays = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $weekLength; $i ++) {
            for($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j ++) {
                $cellIndex = $i * 7 + $j;
                $cellValue = null;
                if ($cellIndex == $firstDayOfTheWeek) {
                    $this->currentDay = 1;
                }
                if (! empty ( $this->currentDay ) && $this->currentDay <= $this->currentMonthDaysLength) {
                    $cellValue = $this->currentDay;
                    $this->currentDay ++;
                }
                $weekDays .= '<li>' . $cellValue . '</li>';
            }
        }
        return $weekDays;
    }

    function getWeekLengthByMonth() {
        $weekLength =  intval ( $this->currentMonthDaysLength / 7 );    
        if($this->currentMonthDaysLength % 7 > 0) {
            $weekLength++;
        }
        $monthStartDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart) );        
        $monthEndingDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-' . $this->currentMonthDaysLength) );
        if ($monthEndingDay < $monthStartDay) {         
            $weekLength++;
        }

        return $weekLength;
    }
}
```

How can I run a loop that gets all the posts from event category, when hyperlink any day of the month if there is an event on that day
NOTE: the loop also needs to work for scheduled posts.

Answer (score 4):

This needs a little more work, but it should get you started.

NOTE: I included the original PHPCalendar Stylesheet inline for my testing.

You are going to have to create an `$arrDaysPosted` index array to contain the information you want to make the calendar link clickable. Right now, it just stores the day.

```
        <?php

    $style=<<<EOL
    <style>
    #calendar-outer {
        width: 574px;
    }

    #calendar-outer ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #calendar-outer ul li {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .prev {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer
    }

    .next {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer
    }

    #currentYear:focus {
        outline: none;
        background: #ff8e8e;
    }

    div.calendar-nav {
        background-color: #ff8e8e;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #FFF;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #calendar-outer .week-name-title li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 27px;
        color: #90918b;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .week-day-cell li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 80px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: #f6ffc6;
        color: #ff8e8e;
        border: 1px solid #f1f0f0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    #body-overlay {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);z-index: 999;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;display: none;}
    #body-overlay div {position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-top:-32px;margin-left:-32px;}
    </style>
    EOL;

    echo $style;


       $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post', // the post type
            'category_name' => 'events', // name of category
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key' => 'field_name', // the name of the custom date field
                'value' => '20190715', // the date to compare it with
                'compare' => '='
                )
            ),
        );
    //$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = $query->posts;
    $daysPosted = [];

    foreach($posts as $post) {
         $arrDaysPosted[] = date("n", $post->post_date_gmt);
    }
    $widget = new calendarWidget($arrDaysPosted);
    echo "WIDGET:". $widget->getCalendarHTML();

    class calendarWidget{
        private $weekDayName = array ("MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN");
        private $currentDay = 0;
        private $currentMonth = 0;
        private $currentYear = 0;
        private $currentMonthStart = null;
        private $currentMonthDaysLength = null;

        function __construct($arrDaysPosted = []) {

            $this->arrDaysPosted = $arrDaysPosted;

            $this->currentYear = date ( "Y", time () );
            $this->currentMonth = date ( "m", time () );

            if (! empty ( $_POST ['year'] )) {
                $this->currentYear = $_POST ['year'];
            }
            if (! empty ( $_POST ['month'] )) {
                $this->currentMonth = $_POST ['month'];
            }
            $this->currentMonthStart = $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-01';
            $this->currentMonthDaysLength = date ( 't', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
        }

        function getCalendarHTML() {
            $calendarHTML = '<div id="calendar-outer">';
            $calendarHTML .= '<div class="calendar-nav">' . $this->getCalendarNavigation() . '</div>';
            $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-name-title">' . $this->getWeekDayName () . '</ul>';
            $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-day-cell">' . $this->getWeekDays ($this->$arrDaysPosted) . '</ul>';
            $calendarHTML .= '</div>';
            return $calendarHTML;
        }

        function getCalendarNavigation() {
            $prevMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart. ' -1 Month'  ) );
            $prevMonthYearArray = explode(",",$prevMonthYear);

            $nextMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart . ' +1 Month'  ) );
            $nextMonthYearArray = explode(",",$nextMonthYear);

            $navigationHTML = '<div class="prev" data-prev-month="' . $prevMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-prev-year = "' . $prevMonthYearArray[1]. '"><</div>';
            $navigationHTML .= '<span id="currentMonth">' . date ( 'M ', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
            $navigationHTML .= '<span contenteditable="true" id="currentYear">'.    date ( 'Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
            $navigationHTML .= '<div class="next" data-next-month="' . $nextMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-next-year = "' . $nextMonthYearArray[1]. '">></div>';
            return $navigationHTML;
        }

        function getWeekDayName() {
            $WeekDayName= '';
            foreach ( $this->weekDayName as $dayname ) {
                $WeekDayName.= '<li>' . $dayname . '</li>';
            }
            return $WeekDayName;
        }

        function _new_getWeekDays() {
            $old_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post', // the post type
                'category_name' => 'events', // name of category
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'field_name', // the name of the custom date field
                    'value' => '20190715', // the date to compare it with
                    'compare' => '='
                    )
                ),
            );
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );

            $events_dates = new WP_Query( $args );

            $weekLength = $this->getWeekLengthByMonth ();
            $firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
            $weekDays = "";
            for($i = 0; $i < $weekLength; $i ++) {
                for($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j ++) {
                    $cellIndex = $i * 7 + $j;
                    $cellValue = null;
                    if ($cellIndex == $firstDayOfTheWeek) {
                        $this->currentDay = 1;
                    }
                    if (! empty ( $this->currentDay ) && $this->currentDay <= $this->currentMonthDaysLength) {
                        $cellValue = $this->currentDay;
                        $this->currentDay ++;
                    }
                    //$weekDays .= '<li>' . $cellValue . '</li>';
                }
            }
            return $weekDays;
        }

        function getWeekDays() {
            $weekLength = $this->getWeekLengthByMonth ();
            $firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
            $weekDays = "";
            for($i = 0; $i < $weekLength; $i ++) {
                for($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j ++) {
                    $cellIndex = $i * 7 + $j;
                    $cellValue = null;
                    if ($cellIndex == $firstDayOfTheWeek) {
                        $this->currentDay = 1;
                    }
                    if (! empty ( $this->currentDay ) && $this->currentDay <= $this->currentMonthDaysLength) {
                        $cellValue = $this->currentDay;

                        if (in_array($this->currentDay, $this->arrDaysPosted)) {
                          $weekDays .= '<li>YES:' . $cellValue . '</li>';
                        } else {
                          $weekDays .= '<li>'. $this->currentDay .'</li>';
                        }

                        $this->currentDay ++;
                    } else {
                      $weekDays .= '<li></li>';
                    }


                }
            }
            return $weekDays;
        }

        function getWeekLengthByMonth() {
            $weekLength =  intval ( $this->currentMonthDaysLength / 7 );
            if($this->currentMonthDaysLength % 7 > 0) {
                $weekLength++;
            }
            $monthStartDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart) );
            $monthEndingDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-' . $this->currentMonthDaysLength) );
            if ($monthEndingDay < $monthStartDay) {
                $weekLength++;
            }

            return $weekLength;
        }
    }


     ?>
```